# Why C# 6.0 doesn't let to set properties of a non-null nullable struct when using Null propagation operator?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, c#-6.0

Assume we have following code :

```
struct Article
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

Article? art = new Article();
art?.Prop1 = "Hi"; // compile-error
```

The compile error is

> CS0131 The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer.

Actually `art?.Prop1` is a property and should be considered as a valid assignment!
I don't see any problem with assignment to make this code invalid.

Why C# 6.0 doesn't let to set properties of a non-null nullable struct ?
Alternately any suggestion for one line code to make assignment valid would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove the question mark in your line `art?.Prop1 = "Hi";` and your assignment should not throw an error.  Make it `art.Prop1 = "Hi";`

Comment: @K.AlanBates He specifically wants to use the null propagation operator.

Comment: Structs are there in C# just to make you life interesting. Try `List<Article> articles = new List<Article>{ new Article() }; article[0].Prop1 = "test";` - maybe you'll reconsider using structs at that point :).

Comment: Mahdi, I've changed title to match the answer - feel free to revert/improve if it does not match you intention.

Comment: @Servy You say he specifically uses it. I say he is accidentally using it and his question is how to make his assignment of "Hi" to Prop1 pass compilation. The easiest way to make it pass compilation is to remove the maybe.

Comment: @K.AlanBates that then removes the desired semantics of supporting the possibly null value.  Making the code compile but fail to work is not a solution, nor is it an explanation of the behavior, which is what he's specifically asking for.  And the fact that he's accepted the answer explaining why the null propagation operator has the semantics it does as opposed to the one claiming that he didn't mean to do what he specifically said he meant to do more or less conclusively answers the question of what he was asking about.

Comment: @Servy ...yeah, and I upvoted that answer about a half hour ago.

Comment: @Servy I thought I read somewhere a while back that during propagated null checks, you run into a problem when trying to propagate through a Nullable; apparently that is not the case so my particular answer was incorrect and I deleted it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code:

```
Article? art
```

will define a `Nullable<Article>` but later when you do:

```
art?.Prop1 = "Hi";
```

This will mean using Null propagation/conditional operator.

Null propagation/conditional operator is for accessing properties, not setting them. Hence you can't use it.

As @Servy said in the comments, the result of Null conditional operator is always a value and you can't assign a value to a value, hence the error.

If you are only trying to set the property then you don't need `?` with the object name, `?` with `Nullable<T>` types is used at the time of declaration, which is syntactic sugar to:

```
Nullable<Article> art; //same as Article? art
```

Comment: Or to say the same thing more technically, the result of the null propagation operator is always a value, never a variable, which is why he's getting the error saying that he can't assign a value to a value, since it's not a variable.

Comment: The question remains why it's not allowed. The compiler could notice that it's an assignment and then use the  null propagation operator to return the variable/property instead of the value or did i overlook something? Could be used to simplify code by omitting null checks before doing an assignment.

Comment: Since you already can call a method like x?.SetValue(...), a property assignment (which is the same thing) should a be a valid option. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

`Article? art` is a shortcut for `Nullable<Article> art`
To assign property you need to access `.Value` field of `Nullable<T>`. In general case you need to ensure art is not null:

```
if (art.HasValue)
{
    art.Value.Prop1 = "Hi"; 
}
```