# Assign property if not null, do nothing otherwise

Tags: c#, properties, nullable

I want to compress this code:

```
if(obj != null)
{
     obj.Name = "Test";
}
```

If `obj` had a explicit method for setting the `Name` I could write

```
obj?.SetName("Test");
```

Is it possible to do so without a explicit method declaration?

Something like:

```
obj?.Name = "Test"; //assign obj.Name to "Test" if obj not null, do nothing if obj is null
```

The last statement gives the following error `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer` which kinda makes sense since `(obj?.Name)` is now a nullable boolean I believe.

---

Edit:
this question seems a duplicate;

[Using the null-conditional operator on the left-hand side of an assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887106/using-the-null-conditional-operator-on-the-left-hand-side-of-an-assignment)