# Set an object's property conditional on the object not being null

Tags: c#, null-conditional-operator

This works, calling Invoke only if the member is not null:

```
List<Command> list = GetCommands();
list.FirstOrDefault(predicate)?.Invoke();
```

Conditionally calling a property setter does not work:

```
list.FirstOrDefault(predicate)?.IsAvailable = true;
```

Instead, an explicit null check must be included:

```
var command = list.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
if (command != null)
    command.IsAvailable = true;
```

I'd have thought it makes sense for a setter given it's essentially sytactical sugar for:

```
list.FirstOrDefault(predicate)?.set_IsAvailable(true);
```

Is there an inline syntax for setting an object's property conditional on the object not being null?

Comment: You can’t use the null-conditional operator as the left side of an assignment.

Comment: _"Instead, an explicit null check must be included:"_ - I don't see anything wrong with that. You can create an extension method if you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the null-conditional operator on the left-hand side of an assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887106/using-the-null-conditional-operator-on-the-left-hand-side-of-an-assignment)

Comment: Oh, I'm fairly sure the answer is "no". Thanks for the link! I think that is comes down the rules for = operators are different to rules for method calls.