# Shorter way to write C# property if object is not null

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I can write:

```
_myVariable?.SetValue(5);
```

It will call `SetValue` only if `_myVariable` is not null, fine.

How can I do the same thing with a Property ? Like (caution, this syntax does not exists):

```
_myVariable?.Value = 5;
```

Since it does not exists (please contradict me), I have to use that good old `if` syntax :

```
if (_myVariable is not null) _myVariable.Value = 5;
```

Property setters and Set functions are, in fact, the same thing except syntax, so I feel upset about this difference.

Do you have any syntax in mind better than good old `if` ?

Comment: If `_myVariable?.Value` evaluates to `null`, what would you be setting?

Comment: The assignation is converted to a method call eventually. But like @JohnathanBarclay mentioned the behavior become really complicated if you see it from the side of where the assignation is going to when the object is null.

Comment: And even worse: What does that say about your logic _if_ you need to set a value on something that in fact _is_ null? Isn't there a bigger design issue?

Comment: It currently isn't possible, but it is being worked on: [relevant github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2883)

Comment: Relevant or duplicate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887106/using-the-null-conditional-operator-on-the-left-hand-side-of-an-assignment