# Null Conditioning operator can't be used for assignments?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Please review the following code and help me visualizing why I am receiving a compiler error.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sample smpl = GetSampleObjectFromSomeClass();

        //Compiler Error -- the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer
        smpl?.isExtended = true; 
    }
}

public class Sample
{
    public bool isExtended { get; set; }
}
```

Should I deduce that null conditioning is only for accessing properties, variables etc. and not for assignment?

Note: I have referred a similar post(link below) but seems to me that not enough discussion occured.[Why C# 6.0 doesn't let to set properties of a non-null nullable struct when using Null propagation operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035022/why-c-sharp-6-0-doesnt-let-to-set-properties-of-a-non-null-nullable-struct-when)

Edit:
I was expecting something like

```
If(null!= smpl) 
{ 
smpl.isExtended = true; 
}
```

Seems like my expectation isn't right!

Comment: What would you expect to happen if smpl is null?

Comment: I would leave the isExtended property untouched. To me this should be If with no else clause.

Comment: @sstan I already posted that in my comments, I didn't find the answer helpful.

Comment: It doesnt matter.

Comment: This isn't voodoo or black magic here. the ?. operator returns the members being accessed in the right hand operand if it is not null, otherwise the stuff on the right is not evaluated and null is returned. Basically the compiler is complaining because what you've written is potentially equivalent to null = true;

Comment: Your deduction is correct. The null-conditional operator only works for member access, not assignment. I tend to agree that the compiler should allow it to be used for Property assignment (but not fields), since property assignment is actually compiled down to a method invocation.The compiled property assignment would look like:  `smpl?.set_isExtended(true);`  Which would be perfectly valid code.

Comment: I disagree with this statement @Jakotheshadows
the ?. operator returns the object if it is not null, otherwise the stuff on the right is not evaluated and null is returned.

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla: `"the stuff on the right is not evaluated and null is returned"` - And what exactly do you expect `null = true;` to do?

Comment: @David I was expecting something like 
If(null!= smpl)
{
  smpl.isExtended = true;
}
Seems like my expectation isn't right!

Comment: @AndrewHanlon: Interesting observation (+1), but semantics and syntax hardly play way together.

Comment: OK, given the comments, I have reopened.

Comment: Not sure why people are asking "what would you expect it to do" - it's obvious what you would expect it to do (from a programmers perspective): If it's not null then make the assignment.

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla I'm not sure what gave you that idea. Could you cite a source? The ?. operator is binary, not unary. Try it yourself by just typing in `var smql = GetSampleObjectFromSomeClass()?.;` and tell me how that compiles for you.

Comment: My guess is the null conditioning operator is not a valid lvalue in the C# language. Polling @jonskeet

Comment: @Gunn yes, I too would expect it to evaluate to if( smpl != null ) smpl.isExtended = true;

Comment: My guess is that is you allow it for properties, people would expect it for fields to work as well, but that is different semantics. Perhaps the language committee just decided to not allow it all together due to this mismatch. A similar scenario is when using `ref` for field access on an instance, which is not allowed for properties.

Comment: @Servy: please reopen, i already closed, then reopened due to interesting comments...

Comment: @leppie It answers the question being asked exactly.  It is a duplicate.  That you'd like to have a discussion about how C# could have been designed instead is off topic from the question asked, and if it *were* what the question is asking, would be Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: @Servy: Read the comments. A valuetype is completely different scenario. A normally setter method on a reference type would have no problem behaving as intended. (I also closed the question at first, then reopened). Please reconsider.

Comment: @leppie The question asks why you can't assign a value to the result of the null conditional member access.  The duplicate answers that; because the result is a value, not a variable.  That is the answer.  The observation that C# could have been designed entirely different to produce a different result is offtopic to that question.

Comment: @Servy: https://twitter.com/andygocke/status/771765830992277504

Comment: @Servy: Consider: `x?.bar = foo` vs `x?.set_bar(foo)` where the latter is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @leppie Yes?  What's your point?  If you want to propose a new language feature for C#, an SO quesiton isn't the appropriate place.  Post a feature request for MS if you would like that feature.  This question asks *why* the first snippet doesn't work, and the duplicate answers that question.  The OP's question is a duplicate, the question you personally have is simply offtopic on SO.

Comment: I had to ask this question again, cause I found not enough to take away from the post. leppie is making a good point so does other participants. I see @jonskeet being called upon, it will be great if we get to hear from him too.
Can you please reopen.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry, I did not realise SO has become an Experts Exchange-type place where only questions and answers are applicable. Apparently the comment feature is useless and should probably be removed.

Comment: @leppie Your comment makes no sense.  I'm not arguing that all comments be prohibited, I'm just saying that the duplicate question answers the question that this question asks, and the entirely separate question you're personally more interested in isn't on topic on SO.  That's not an argument that there's no need to have comments on posts.

Comment: As workaround you could implement a generic extension method for setting arbitrary types of properties:

public static void SetValue<T>(this T property, T value)
{
    property = value;
}
And use it like
art?.Prop1.SetValue("Hello");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your deduction is correct. The null-conditional operator only works for member access, not assignment.

That said, I tend to agree that the language/compiler should allow the operator to be used for property assignment (but not fields), since property assignment is actually compiled down to a method invocation.

The compiled property assignment would look like:

```
smpl?.set_isExtended(true);
```

Which would be perfectly valid code.

On the other hand, it is easy to make the argument that it would introduce syntax discrepancies between property and field usage that currently do not exist, as well as make the code harder to reason around.

You can also access most of the [C# 6.0 design notes](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CSharp%20Language%20Design%20Notes) on codeplex. I made a cursory scan, and the null-conditional discussion spans many sections.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the implications of this line of code:

```
smpl?.isExtended = true;
```

If `smpl` *was* `null`, you would be trying to assign a value to `null`.  Which doesn't make sense.

Just assign the value, there's no need for null checking there:

```
smpl.isExtended = true;
```

Basically, the null propagation operator is to be used for *reading* values, not for *setting* them.  Consider this line of code:

```
var x = someObject?.someProperty;
```

Conceptually, what this means is that `x` will be assigned the value of `someProperty` if `someObject` exists.  If it doesn't exist (is `null`) then `x` will be `null`.

What, conversely, would this mean?:

```
someObject?.someProperty = x;
```

Conceptually this would mean that if `someObject` exists, then set `someProperty` to `x`.  But if it doesn't exist (is `null`) then... set `null` to `x`?  This doesn't make sense:

```
null = x;
```

Comment: Made edits just to make my case clear, @David

Comment: @Vivek_Shukla: I've updated the answer as well.  Basically, consider what would happen in the code in either case (is `null` vs. is not `null`).  One of those two cases makes no sense.  So the compiler refuses it.

Comment: Could it not mean: if `someObject` exists, then invoke `someObject.set_someProperty(x)` else do nothing.

Comment: I was thinking along the same line, @LeeGunn

Comment: As @LeeGunn hints at, isn't the property just a setter method in this case? I don't get it. Seems like an oversight.