# c# Single line object null check before assigning its property a value

Tags: c#, null-check

I am trying to simplify this logic into a single line of code perhaps using the null-coalescing operator, but I could not find an example of this exact scenario, though this is very common

```
if(obj!=null)
{
  obj.prop = false;
}
```

Where **obj** is an object

**prop** is a property

Can this be written in a single line without using the if statement for null check ?
I know I can do `var myVar = obj?.prop ;` [This null check is only permitted for getting the value, not setting the value]

Comment: What do you want to happen in a single line if your **obj** is null? How are you going to set a property on a null object?

Comment: Like when you find out the **obj** is null, you will then have to create an instance of that object in order to set a property of it, right?

Comment: For clarification, are you asking for a theoretical option that would look like `obj?.prop = value;` where it sets the value of the property only if the object is not null?

Comment: Question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887106/using-the-null-conditional-operator-on-the-left-hand-side-of-an-assignment

Comment: Something I use sometimes for this situation is the `??` operator. Can be used like so: `var currentObject = obj ?? new Obj() { prop = true };` Where if your `obj` is null, it will be able to use an instance that is created right there, with the properties set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why C# 6.0 doesn't let to set properties of a non-null nullable struct when using Null propagation operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035022/why-c-sharp-6-0-doesnt-let-to-set-properties-of-a-non-null-nullable-struct-when)